# bound for binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

How can one show $\displaystyle\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m ! (n-1)!}\leq \left[\frac{e (m+n-1)}{n}\right]^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: Have you tried Stirling's approximation?

Comment: Surely this is homework question. I did a course this year and that was the first question on the first problem sheet. 

Comment: I did try Stirling's approximation but am unable to get this expression.

Comment: The first and obvious approach is to use induction on $n$. In http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11139-006-0075-1 (see also http://arXiv.org/abs/math/0304021) I had a similar estimate; there however the deal was bout the beta-integral. So, if you take the reciprocal of both sides you can use the estimate from that paper (it's quite sharp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote the quotient of the right and left hand sides,
$$
f(m,n)=\biggl(\frac{e(m+n-1)}n\biggr)^{n-1}\bigg/\binom{m+n-1}m.
$$
Then $f(m,1)=1$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$ and
$$
\frac{f(m,n+1)}{f(m,n)} 
=\frac{e}{\biggl(1+\dfrac1n\biggr)^n}\cdot\biggl(1+\frac1{m+n-1}\biggr)^{n-1} > 1,
$$
that is,
$$
f(m,n+1)> f(m,n)>\dots> f(m,2)> f(m,1)=1.
$$
This proves the required inequality.

Comment: Thankyou, but I am still rather curious to know how one arrives at such an inequality ? Supposing I dont know this bound and am interested to find a bound, ( I cannot use induction then).  I suppose there has to be a way to get a good bound. Is there ? 
 

Comment: The main property of the binomial coefficients is that the quotients of consecutive terms is rational in both parameters. Then you try to approximate this quotient by a simpler function... Another source of extimates for the binomials is Stirling's formula for the gamma function (mentioned above by Scott). Then one can use the beta integral (which is the reciprocal of a binomial coefficient) and do the estimates for it.

Answer (score 4):

Another immediate proof can be obtained from
 $$
\frac{(m+n-1)!}{m!}\le(m+n-1)^{n-1}
 $$
(which is obvious) and
 $$
\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{n-1}\le(n-1)!
 $$
which after multiplying by $n$ and taking logs becomes
 $$
n\log(n)-n+1\le\sum_{k=2}^{n}\log(k)
 $$
which is immediate as the RHS is an obvious upper bound for 
 $$
\int_1^n\log(x)\,dx=(x\log(x)-x)|_1^n=n\log(n)-n+1.
 $$

Comment: Vladimir, this OP is the 2nd one when our solutions are compared from the "easyness" point of view (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25855/). The two solutions are equally easy and equally standard... :-)

Comment: Wadim, I couldn't agree more - they are both easy and standard indeed.

Comment: Vladimir, I have a special smile for this: $\dddot\smile$