# Upper bounds on hypergeometric function $_3F_2$ for stipulated parameters

Tags: hypergeometric-functions

Are there any existing bounds on the hypergeometric function $_3F_2(-m,-n,1/2;1,1;4)$ where $m,n \geq 1$? Or any thoughts how one can be obtained?

Most of the inequalities I've seen apply to the cases whose acceptable parameter ranges are applicable to the above.

Comment: Derek, for your terminating series the standard techniques oulined in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33374/partial-sums-of-the-chu-vandermonde-identity/33382#33382 can be applied.