# Bijective proof of weak form of Stirling's approximation

Tags: co.combinatorics, computer-science

There are short and sweet proofs of various forms of Stirling's approximation. But even the sweetest among them don't instill the same conviction in the reader as a direct bijective proof.

Computer scientists can often get away with a very weak form of Stirling's approximation:

$$(n/2)^{n/2} \leq n! \leq n^n$$

From this follows

$$(n/2)\ log(n) - (n/2)\ log(2) \leq log(n!) \leq n\ log(n)$$

and therefore $log(n!) = \Theta(n\ log(n))$. This is sufficient to establish the lower bound on comparison-based sorting algorithms and many other asymptotic bounds.

> Does anyone know a natural bijective proof of $(n/2)^{n/2} \leq n! \leq n^n$?

Comment: Why it's important to have a *bijective* proof?! I would be very happy to hear some motivation. Any way, if you wish to have some combinatorics involved, you should clarify how to interpret $(n/2)^{n/2}$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: For $n$ even, $n/2$ of the factors of $n!$ are at least $n/2$. So, the natural interpretation for $n$ odd is to round down $n/2$. But I would be happy with a bijective proof that only directly encompasses the even case. As for why I want a bijective proof? The usual reason of wanting to see the underlying combinatorial structure.

Comment: For a stronger lower bound which implies yours, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27912/bound-for-binomial-coefficients/27928#27928 .

Comment: By the way, maybe I should mention my original intuition that the lower bound should have something to do with the existence of fixed-point-free involutions on sets of even cardinality. 

Comment: Btw, as to elementary forms of the Stirling inequality, note also $e^n\geq \frac{n^n}{n!}$ from the exponential series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think of all maps from the first $n/2$ elements of {$1,...,n$} to the last $n/2$.  Say, let $a_1< \ldots < a_k \to z$.  Make a cycle $a_1 \to a_2 \to \ldots \to a_k \to z \to a_1$.  Do this for all $z$.  The details are straightforward.  This proves the lower bound.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks! This also works in the odd $n$ case by fixing the median element.

Answer (score 2):

n! counts one-to-one functions from {1,2,...,n} to itself while $n^n$ counts all such functions. For a bijective proof of the lower bound one would likely want n=2m,  Then the lower number is   the $m^m$ functions g from {1,...,m} to itself . I thought I had an easy bijection to a class of partial one-to-one functions but the on I had isn't right...

Comment: Yeah, the upper bound poses no problem. I too have had a couple of false starts on a bijective proof of the lower bound, so I'm sympathetic to your mistake. :)

Comment: OK, its not so pretty but one-to-one functions from {1,...,m} to {1,...,n} number n*(n-1)*...*(m+1) and all m terms are greater than m. So take any of the m^m functions g from {1..m} to itself and make a function f by assigning in turn f(1),f(2),... where f(i) is the g(i)th in order from the things not already assigned.